# How do I make ebyte transceiver transmit faster per second

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-c++

So I acquired an Ebyte transceiver variant and  found a library for it written in c language/Arduino,
and I want to increase transmission speed of the transceiver to let's say 8 transmission per second.

I have been able to push the the transmission speed to 4 transmissions per second by tweaking some of the timeout variables in the the library. To Further increase the speed of transmission, I tried to apply the values in this [EBYTE.h](https://github.com/KrisKasprzak/EBYTE/blob/master/EBYTE.h) file provided by the author of the library by increasing the baud rate, air data rate and speed but transmission speed still did not increase above 4 transmissions per second. below is what I have tried:

```
/*

  This example shows how to connect to an EBYTE transceiver
  using an ESP32

/*

  This example shows how to connect to an EBYTE transceiver
  using an ESP32

  This code for for the sender

  ESP32 won't allow SoftwareSerial (at least I can't get that lib to work
  so you will just hardwire your EBYTE directly to the Serial2 port


*/

#include "EBYTE.h"


/*
WARNING: IF USING AN ESP32
DO NOT USE THE PIN NUMBERS PRINTED ON THE BOARD
YOU MUST USE THE ACTUAL GPIO NUMBER
*/
#define PIN_RX 16   // Serial2 RX (connect this to the EBYTE Tx pin)
#define PIN_TX 17   // Serial2 TX pin (connect this to the EBYTE Rx pin)

#define PIN_M0 4    // D4 on the board (possibly pin 24)
#define PIN_M1 22   // D2 on the board (possibly called pin 22)
#define PIN_AX 21   // D15 on the board (possibly called pin 21)


// i recommend putting this code in a .h file and including it
// from both the receiver and sender modules
struct DATA {
  unsigned long Count;
  int Bits;
  float Volts;
  float Amps;

};

// these are just dummy variables, replace with your own
int Chan;
DATA MyData;
unsigned long Last;


// create the transceiver object, passing in the serial and pins
EBYTE Transceiver(&Serial2, PIN_M0, PIN_M1, PIN_AX);

void setup() {


  Serial.begin(19200);

  Serial.println("Starting Reader");

  // this init will set the pinModes for you
  
  Serial2.begin(19200);

  Transceiver.init();
  Transceiver.SetMode(MODE_PROGRAM);
  Transceiver.SetSpeed(19200);
  Transceiver.SetTransmitPower(OPT_TP20);
  Transceiver.SetUARTBaudRate(UDR_19200);
  Transceiver.SetAirDataRate(ADR_19200);
  Transceiver.SetAddressH(0);
  Transceiver.SetAddressL(0);
  Transceiver.SetChannel(13);

  Transceiver.SaveParameters(PERMANENT);
  Transceiver.Reset();

  Transceiver.PrintParameters();
  Transceiver.SetMode(MODE_NORMAL);
  Transceiver.Reset();
  

  Serial2.flush();

}

void loop() {

  // measure some data and save to the structure
  MyData.Count++;
  MyData.Bits = analogRead(A0);
  MyData.Volts = MyData.Bits * ( 5.0 / 1024.0 );

  // i highly suggest you send data using structures and not
  // a parsed data--i've always had a hard time getting reliable data using
  // a parsing method
  Transceiver.SendStruct(&MyData, sizeof(MyData));

    // note, you only really need this library to program these EBYTE units
    // you can call write directly on the EBYTE Serial object
    // Serial2.write((uint8_t*) &Data, PacketSize );


  // let the use know something was sent
  Serial.print("Sending: "); Serial.println(MyData.Count);
  delay(8);


}
```

What I tried in the code above was based on the counsel of the author of the library as indicated in the issue I raised on the library in the link below:
https://github.com/KrisKasprzak/EBYTE/issues/65

link for configurable parameters: [EBYTE.h](https://github.com/KrisKasprzak/EBYTE/blob/master/EBYTE.h)

Link to library: [text](https://github.com/KrisKasprzak/EBYTE/blob/master/EBYTE.cpp)

I also tried to supply value outside of the specified parameters in the EBYTE.h file but found out that the values supplied in bytes does not match the labels  e.g

```
// air data rates (certian types of modules)
// (must be the same for transmitter and reveiver)
#define ADR_300 0b000       // 300 baud
#define ADR_1200 0b001      // 1200 baud
#define ADR_2400 0b010      // 2400 baud
#define ADR_4800 0b011      // 4800 baud
#define ADR_9600 0b100      // 9600 baud
**#define ADR_19200 0b101       // 19200 baud**
```

converting 0b101 from byte to decimal does not equal 19200

Answer (score 0):

This values (`ADR_*`) are not meant to represent numbers directly. Method `SetAirDataRate()` use this values to construct some complex value in `_Speed` variable which is fed into `Serial2` in `SaveParameters()` method.

After examination of `SendStruct()` method it looks like there is a lot of housekeeping with timers to maintain stable state transitions. I didn't dig it completely, but overall it's hard to say where you can make safe gains. Try to consult with datasheet for device and try different sizes of your data structure to see how much of the delay is attributed to it to get an idea of actual transfer speed.

Comment: I am using a small data structure which is below the maximum packet size. I already consulted with device manual to determine other info to enable achieve my requirement; however, the library author and datasheet provider aren't the same. here is a link to data sheet for my exact device: https://www.ebyte.com/en/pdf-down.aspx?id=310

Comment: and https://www.ebyte.com/en/product-view-news.html?id=153